# "Repository doesn't support architecture" when trying to update on Landscape client

Tags: apt, landscape

When I try to update on landscape client machine I get this error.

```
$ sudo apt-get update
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'restricted/binary-i386/Packages'
 as repository 'http://landscape/repository/standalone/xenial xenial-updates InRelease'
 doesn't support architecture 'i386'
```

Is there any simple way to add arch i386 without having to create a new pocket, using only CLI?

Answer (score 0):

The APi has an [EditPocket](https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/api/repositories.html#editpocket) method which takes a list of architectures. Something like this should allow you to change the list of architectures of a pocket:

```
landscape-api edit-pocket pocket series distribution --architectures amd64,i386
```

Comment: thanks , very helpful info... my follow up is the link shared  is for HTML , is the a link for CLI as well. like for the command you gave

Comment: The link is for for the http API, which landscape-api CLI uses. The method names are formatted slightly differently though (e.g. edit-pocket -> EditPocket). There is more documentation about it here https://landscape.canonical.com/static/doc/api/api-client-package.html